# The Article "Understanding the StackOverflow Database Schema"-- Is it An Officially Sanctioned Article?

Tags: discussion, database-design

I found that there is an article entitled [Understanding the StackOverflow Database Schema](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema), I wonder how and where did the author get the source of information?

Is it from public SO blog posts and articles and data dumps, or the author has other private information that can only come from the horse mouth?

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes to both.  The author (Brent Ozar) did some work for the SO team and does have special knowledge of the real schema.  However, this article specifically targets the monthly data dump.

Comment: "Special knowledge", I like that.  I'm going to have to use that in my slide deck intros.  "Ladies and gentlemen, I have Special Knowledge."  ;-)

Comment: Oh, and yes, Joel's answer is right.  The article just talks about the monthly data dump.  When I wrote that article, I did get some of the field sizes from the actual database, but only so I could make sure the exports didn't overflow when I inserted 'em into a new database.  The real database schema doesn't match up with the export.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the article, it sounds like it's just talking about the public dumps. Following the 'data mining the so database' link leads to a description of downloading the dump.